# List comprehension to combine elements of sublists by column

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, nameerror

I have a list of lists like so:

```
allrows = [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW46550', 'sersic', 20.04, 21.12],
['NEPW89344', 'NEPW89346', 'sersic', 20.33, 19.66], ...]
```

And I'd like to create a new list of lists, where each list corresponds to one "column". My desired output is:

```
cols = [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW89344', ...], ['NEPW46550', 'NEPW89346', ...], ['sersic', 'sersic', ...], [20.04, 20.33, ...], [21.12, 19.66, ...]]
```

I figured I could accomplish this with list comprehension, like this:

```
cols = [[row[n] for row in allrows] for n in range(len(row))]
```

But I get a `NameError` that `row` is not defined. I tried to also switch the orders of my loop statements, but that did not give me my desired output (instead it gave me exactly what I started with). How can I achieve my desired output with list comprehension?

Comment: `zip()` it......

Comment: @Chris_Rands Thanks, but I was specifically asking about the list comprehension method here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the purpose of the built in `zip` function. You just need to unpack your lists as you call it. Something like:

```
allrows = [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW46550', 'sersic', 20.04, 21.12],
           ['NEPW89344', 'NEPW89346', 'sersic', 20.33, 19.66]]

for item in zip(*allrows): # unpack with *allrows
    print(item)
```

Nets you:

```
('NEPW46486', 'NEPW89344')
('NEPW46550', 'NEPW89346')
('sersic', 'sersic')
(20.04, 20.33)
(21.12, 19.66)
```

If for some reason `zip()` is unsatisfactory, to make a list comprehension it is usually easiest to make the actual code structure and then condense it. Starting with:

```
cols = []
for index, item in enumerate(allrows[0]):
    col = []
    for row in allrows:
        col.append(row[index])
    cols.append(col)
print(cols)
```

We get the desired

> [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW89344'], ['NEPW46550', 'NEPW89346'], ['sersic', 'sersic'], [20.04, 20.33], [21.12, 19.66]]

So then we can just condense it to a single line like:

```
cols = [[row[index] for row in allrows] for index, item in enumerate(allrows[0])]
print(cols)
```

Which again yields:

> [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW89344'], ['NEPW46550', 'NEPW89346'], ['sersic', 'sersic'], [20.04, 20.33], [21.12, 19.66]]

Comment: Thank you, but I was curious if I could accomplish the same thing with list comprehension (trying to work on my list comprehension skills). Or is it not possible?

Comment: @curious_cosmo yes, it is possible

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in a list comprehension using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function like this:

```
allrows = [['NEPW46486', 'NEPW46550', 'sersic', 20.04, 21.12],
           ['NEPW89344', 'NEPW89346', 'sersic', 20.33, 19.66],]

cols = [list(col) for col in zip(*allrows)]
```

Result:

```
[['NEPW46486', 'NEPW89344'], ['NEPW46550', 'NEPW89346'], ['sersic', 'sersic'], [20.04, 20.33], [21.12, 19.66]]
```

This is sometimes called "[transposing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)" (meaning the swapping of columns for rows) a 2D matrix of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a list of tuples, you can simply do:

```
list(zip(*allrows))  # python 3
```

or

```
zip(*allrows)  # python 2
```